# Microsoft Azure Devops: How to regenerate repo access password?

Tags: git, azure, github, azure-devops, repo

I have a repo hosted on Microsoft Azure Devops, when I created a repo I created credentials  to be able to push/pull etc.

After a while, the password expired and I looked everywhere to try to find how to regenerate it and I couldn't find anything.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the term you're looking for is a [Personal Access Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows#create-a-pat) (PAT). The documentation may differ slightly for AzDO Server. I found it by selecting my Profile and then "Security".

Note that PATs are not repo specific, but instead provide the same repo level access that your user has, except for what can be further limited by the token specific permissions you see when you create it.